# Mediation with covariates using mediation package in R: Error in model.frame.default... factor has new levels

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to run a bootstrap-based causal mediation analysis with mediator and outcome variable models that include one pre-treatment covariate. The covariate is categorical with 16 levels. The documentation for the [mediation package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) seems like it should be able to do this, but I get this error when I use it:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor cov has new levels 13
```

Here is an example that should reproduce the error:

```
set.seed(542)
treatment <- sample(c("c", "t"),226, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
med <- sample(0:6, 226, replace=TRUE)
cov <- as.factor(c(rep(1,16), rep(2,15), rep(3,11), rep(4,13), rep(5,10), rep(6,18), 
                   rep(7,11), rep(8,14), rep(9,9), rep(10,13), rep(11,12), rep(12,19),
                   rep(13,7), rep(14,11), rep(15,11), rep(16,36)))
dv <- sample(0:15, 226, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(treatment, med, cov, dv)

set.seed(542)
med.fit <- lm(med ~ treatment + cov, data=data)
out.fit <- lm(dv ~ med + treatment + cov, data=data)
med.out <- mediation::mediate(med.fit, out.fit, boot=TRUE, treat="treatment", 
                              mediator="med", sims=1000, control.value = "c", treat.value = "t")
summary(med.out)
```

Weirdly this error does not seem to occur if I only use 100 simulations. Also, when I was creating the example and let the covariate values distribute evenly across the 16 levels, the error did not occur, so instead I've recreated the exact distribution of my covariate data. (Maybe it's something about only 7 observations falling into the "13" category?)

I'm looking for any solution that would allow me to include this covariate in my mediator and outcome models, whether it's using this package or something else. Thoughts?

Please let me know if there is any more information I should provide!

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @PatrickWilliams I didn't receive an answer, but think I figured out why it's happening. I think the bootstrapping form of the mediate function is sampling rows with replacement, which means that not all the observations are selected in each simulation. Since the cov group 13 has so few observations, it's less likely to get selected and whenever the function hits a simulation that doesn't include an observation from that group (more likely the more simulations), it spits out that error.

Comment: @PatrickWilliams The only way I can think of to fix it is to find the part of the function pulling the samples and add criteria that each selection has to include at least one observation from each group in order to be used, but that's way beyond my ability level!

Comment: Thanks kaytee238. That makes sense and I appreciate your clear response!